# Rails - complicated query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am new to rails, and Im having hard time writing a query using rails' methods.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a Canteen model that has many Meals, however I want to only display meals that are being served that day.

So I created a Canteen model, that has_many Meals.
Then I created Served_date model, that belongs_to meal and Meal has_many Served_dates so we can specify multiple dates when the meal is being served.

How would I make query like this?

//P.S.: `Served_date.where(served_at: Date.today)` returns Served_dates that are being served today

Thanks !

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you plan on having more than one canteen? And can a meal have many canteens? And what attributes does the Served_date model have?

Comment: Yes, there are going to be multiple canteens (its meant for my university). Canteen - Meal relationship was suppose to be many_to_many because multiple canteens serve for example fried cheese, but then I realised they never cost the same so It would create unnecessary problems, therefore its only a on_to_many relationship. ServedDate has only servered_at:date and foreign key that references meal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the model name should not be underscored by convention, hence you should use ServedDate instead of Served_date.

This query should give you what you need:

```
Meal.joins(:served_dates).where(served_dates: {served_at: Date.today})
```

Better yet, you can parameterize it and turn it into a scope to be more portable:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :served_on, lambda{|date| joins(:served_dates).where(served_dates: {served_at: date}) }
end
```

And then call:

```
Meal.served_on(Date.today)
```

Comment: Thanks! Btw is it possible incorporate it into a show action like Canteen.find(params[:id]).meals.served_on(Date.today) or do I have to modify the query?

Comment: Absolutely, you can do this.  Scopes can be called on associations and can be chained with other scopes as well.